# How does this equation for the Fibonacci sequence work using powershell?

Tags: powershell-4.0

The original equation is below:

$($c=$p=1; while ($c -lt 100) {$c; $c,$p=($c+$p),$c})

The portion I do not understand, is below:

{$c; $c,$p=($c+$p),$c}

Would anyone be able to explain what is happening in layman's terms?

Thank you, it is much appreciated.

Comment: `$c;` means print `c` and `$c,$p=($c+$p),$c` means `replace (c,p) with (c+p, c)`

Comment: Got it! Now it makes sense lol. Gracias!